# is there an easy way to generate a table_query based off of a timezone difference in BigQuery?

Tags: google-bigquery

### Legacy SQL

I'm using GBQ's legacy SQL to query tables dynamically using the `TABLE_QUERY` function.  I dynamically generate the table name to query based on `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.  For example, I select devices from the past 14 days of hit data in tables that are partitioned by quarter (ie. mydataset.hit_data_[1-4]).

### Standard SQL

I need to convert the timezones to PST.  GBQ Standard SQL has `TIME ZONE` conversions.  Switching to Standard SQL, I am able to convert timezones using the GBQ Standard SQL.  But if I now try to use a TABLE_QUERY in the same query, to do what I was doing in the Legacy SQL version, I get:

`Error: Table-valued functions are not supported`

### Using both

Is there a way to have the best of both worlds?  I would like to query mydataset.hit_data_3 and mydataset.hit_data_4 based on the current timestamp in Q4, if the previous 14 days overlap into Q3.

`SELECT
  device
  FROM
    TABLE_QUERY(mydataset, 'table_id = CONCAT(\"hit_data_\", STRING(QUARTER(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "America/Los_Angeles")))) OR table_id = CONCAT(\"hit_data_\", STRING(QUARTER(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "America/Los_Angeles"), INTERVAL -14 DAY)))) ')
      WHERE
        DATE(date_time) BETWEEN DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'America/Los_Angeles'), INTERVAL -14 DAY))
        AND DATE(CURRENT_DATE())
    ;`

It looks ugly, but in GBQ it should be valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard SQL doesn't support TABLE_QUERY or TABLE_DATE_RANGE functions. Instead it supports wildcard tables with a special pseudo column _TABLE_SUFFIX:

You should be able to rewrite your query with a WHERE clause on _TABLE_SUFFIX pseudo column

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables

Comment: Thanks, Pavan.  Is there any word on whether this will support views one day?

Comment: Can you briefly tell us the use case for querying multiple views in this fashion? Could you define a single view that achieves this by using the filter on _TABLE_SUFFIX inside the view definition itself?

Comment: I think we could define a single view that uses _TABLE_SUFFIX, but currently the naming convention on our tables appends _v to the original table_name.  So _TABLE_SUFFIX matching tablename* will match all the views unintentionally and error.

Answer (score 1):

with BigQuery Standard SQL you should use [_TABLE_SUFFIX](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#filtering_selected_tables_using_table_suffix) pseudo column that allows you to chose table(s) to query from

Below is direction to go

```
SELECT * 
FROM `mydataset.hit_data_*` 
WHERE (_TABLE_SUFFIX = STRING(QUARTER(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "America/Los_Angeles")))
OR _TABLE_SUFFIX = STRING(QUARTER(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "America/Los_Angeles"), INTERVAL -14 DAY)))
)
AND DATE(date_time) BETWEEN 
      DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'America/Los_Angeles'), INTERVAL -14 DAY)) 
    AND DATE(CURRENT_DATE())
```

Note: you need to make sure you are using functions supported by Standard SQL
For example instead of

```
QUARTER(TIMESTAMP(...))
```

you should use

```
EXTRACT(QUARTER FROM TIMESTAMP(...))
```